# FirebaseVisionImage: variable 'image' might not have been initialized

Tags: java, android, machine-learning, firebase-mlkit

I'm trying to use the example for Google Firebase (machine learning kit) in Android Studio. I'm getting an error when passing the image variable into the detector.processImage method (error shown below).

How can I get past this error? I have to use the FirebaseVisionImage.fromFilePath within a try-catch block, but the error message is telling me that the image variable may not be initialized.

> error: variable image might not have been initialized

```
        FirebaseVisionImage image;

        try {
            image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFilePath(MainMenuActivity.this,
                    Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/Download/test.jpg")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getOnDeviceTextRecognizer();

        Task<FirebaseVisionText> result = detector.processImage(image)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseVisionText>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(FirebaseVisionText firebaseVisionText) {
                        // Task completed successfully
                        mainText.setText("Hello!");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(
                        new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                // Task failed with an exception
                            }
                        }
                );
```

Comment: Because you initialize the image inside the try-catch there is a possibility it won't be initialized. You could move the rest of your code inside the try-catch or perhaps check if the image has been initialized befre you try to use it.

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should only be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it.

Comment: Got it, sorry about that. First time posting a question on stackoverflow, will make sure to use the tags more appropriately next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error emerges because of this piece of code

```
FirebaseVisionImage image;

try {
  image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFilePath(
             MainMenuActivity.this,
             Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/Download/test.jpg"))
          );
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now, ask yourself, what happens to `image` if an `Exception` is thrown inside the `try` block?
The variable **might** have been assigned a valid value, or it **might have not**.

Because you're letting the execution flow to continue (you aren't throwing the `Exception` to the upper level), the compiler cannot know that for sure, since the exception is thrown at run-time.
And because in Java a local variable must be initialized before usage (even with `= null`), the compiler is telling you to do so.

> error: variable image might not have been initialized

The solution might be to initialize it with `null`

```
FirebaseVisionImage image = null;
```

Or, **a better one**, to let escape the `Exception`. That will signal there is a bug.
You'll also be able to completely unwrap your code from the `try - catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

All code that needs the image should be inside the `try` block:

```
try {
    FirebaseVisionImage image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFilePath(MainMenuActivity.this,
            Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/Download/test.jpg")));
    Task<FirebaseVisionText> result = detector.processImage(image)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseVisionText>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FirebaseVisionText firebaseVisionText) {
                // Task completed successfully
                mainText.setText("Hello!");
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(
                new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        // Task failed with an exception
                    }
                }
        );
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getOnDeviceTextRecognizer();
```

Note that a `catch` statement that just prints the runtime exception like yours does, should usually be as high as possible in the callstack. So I'd recommend moving it to the code that alls this code, or even higher up. And keep in mind: if you don't catch that error at all, Android will print it too. So consider what you're trying to accomplish with this `catch` and implement it accordingly.